# What does %prec '.' mean here in yacc?

Tags: yacc

```
notype_declarator:
      notype_declarator '(' parmlist_or_identifiers  %prec '.'
        { $$ = build_nt (CALL_EXPR, $1, $3, NULL_TREE); }
```

Anyone familiar with yacc rules?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It declares that the construct has the same precedence as the '.' operator, which have been specified earlier.

Comment: Which symbol do you refer to by `that construct`?

Comment: The whole expression before the `%prec`, actually.  It's telling `yacc` how to disambiguate that branch of the parse tree relative to other similar branches.

Answer (score 0):

yacc program for showing error for
1) redeclaration of variable
2) Assignment expression error
3) operator missing